# How to use 2 monitors with a laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop that supports 2 external monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/177427/laptop-that-supports-2-external-monitors)

I am in the market for a new laptop, and I'm wondering if there are any that support 2 external monitors, plus the built-in screen? I don't want to use the Matrox DualHead or TripleHead connectors. Are there any laptops that provide 2 external connectors?

Comment: Have you considered [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/) or [VTBook](http://www.villagetronic.com/vtbook/index.html) or something similar?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/177427/laptop-that-supports-2-external-monitors)

Comment: I have a USB monitor, the quality is terrible. :(

Comment: They look fine, at resolutions that they support.  They just don't have much in the way of acceleration.  This is by FAR the easiest way to add monitors.